# from distribution to histogram variables matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have 2 variables x and y

```
x= randi([50 100],1,1000)';

y= randi([8 100],1,1000)';

acc = accumarray(x, y);
figure
bar(acc)
```

how can I get the same plot using the `hist` function?

in particular I need the variable unknown for which
`hist(unknown)` produces the same plot than `bar(acc)`

Comment: i don't really understand your last question, because 'unknow' should be egal to x to obtain the same result.

Comment: the function bar just plot what is acc. the function hist "counts" the frequency of the elements in unknown...I think there is a relantionship between acc and unknown

Comment: exactly hist count the number of element between 2 bins and accumarray sum the element. For example A = accumarray(x,1) will give the same result as A = hist(x);

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your `y` vector.

So we obtain:

```
hist(x,sort(y));
```

And if you can use histogram() instead of hist(); (recommanded by mathworks)

```
histogram(x,sort(y));
```

And be careful because here your bins are not regular ! perhaps you have better to use `y = linespace(8,100,1000)` (regular bins spacing) but of course the result will be a little be different.